# Root of sum of shifted polynomials

Tags: calculus, roots

For an arbitrary positive odd integer $k$, I would like to obtain an expression for the root $x_{root} \in \mathbb{R}$ of the following polynomial
$$p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N (x-x_i)^k,$$
where $x_i\in \mathbb{R}$, for all $i \in \{1,2,...,N\}$.
For example, when $k=1$, we can trivially see that $x_{root} = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i/N$. I am stuck in finding a general expression for higher $k$'s.

Also, for all $k$ and $x_i$'s under the previously mentioned conditions, $p(x)$ has one real root because it is a sum of non-decreasing functions.

Comment: Maybe there's no neat answer. Try -2, 1, 1 for $k=3$, see whether it looks like there will be any nice answer for that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root is also a root for the general $k$ when $N=1$ or $2$.  Since $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ we have for example for $k=3$, $N=2$ case
$$
(x-x_1)^3+(x-x_2)^3=(2x-x_1-x_2)((x-x_1)^2-(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(x-x_2)^2)
$$
which has the root $(x_1+x_2)/2$ as well as two more.  Possibly the average is the answer for all odd $k$ and all values of $N$. You could try plugging in the average and see what happens for various other $k$ and $N$.

Comment: Not for all $N$, surely. Try 1, 2, 6 with average 3; for odd $k$ you get $1+2^k-3^k$, rarely zero.